# Chart Open Orders by Month Using Open and Close Dates

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

Problem statement:
I have orders in Excel with the dates the orders were opened, and the date the order was closed. I'd like to show a chart by month showing the number of orders that were open during that given month.

What I've done:
I created a column for each month, then created a formula that returns one or zero based on whether it was open during that month. Then I sum up the total at the bottom of the column

What I'm looking for:
A different solution, one which may lead to a pivot table that would make it easier to incorporate other data fields, for instance type of product etc.

Comment: Add more details about how your data is organized and how you want the answer to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you have looks like:

[image]

and you want to have the ability to produce a pivot table and chart like:

[image]

You could transpose your data and create column headings similar to what has been done at the top of the second picture.